# Where does Lua indexing only applies to?

Tags: indexing, lua

let me start by showing my line of codes:

```
    local names = {}
    str = "Hello World"
    for count = 0, #str do
         names[count] = string.sub(str, count, count)
         names[count].id = count
    end
```

BTW, this is just a sample but my concept is there. Anyway, it keeps returning an error saying attempt to index field '?' (a nil value). What does this error mean? i tried using something like this in my other project it worked just fine. Except, it was an image, still why does it not apply to this instance? where does indexing apply to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue here is you're getting confused about how to use the default lua value types. tables and userdata are the only two datatypes where you will set/get properties. i'll break down your code so maybe it'll help you understand how to use tables to do what you want...

you start off creating an empty table called names. there are no values or attributes within that table that you can reference at all.

```
local names = {}
```

in your for loop, you pull out a character from string 'str' one character at a time and assign it to names at index pointed to by count (which should start at 1, btw.. because string and table indices in lua are 1 based, not zero based). so on the second loop you're essentially doing this:

```
names[1] = 'H'
```

(first loop the counter is 0, so string.sub(str, 0, 0) returns an empty string)

directly after that, you're doing a couple of steps at once, and this is where you're getting confused. breaking it out should clear it up for you.

```
local a_char = names[count] -- get the string value in index 'count'
a_char.id = count           -- try to set property id on that string value
names[count] = a_char       -- assign this value to index 'count' in table names
```

the code above is logically equivalent to names[count].id = count. you're trying to create/set a property called 'id' on a string value. strings do not have that property and you aren't allowed to create it, and this is why the interpreter barks at you.

if you want to store logical information together in a lua table, the norm is to use nested tables. it sounds like you want to basically store each character in string 'str' along with its position in the table 'names'. this would be how you do that:

```
local names = {}
str = "Hello World"
for count = 1, #str do
    local cha, idx = string.sub(str, count, count), count
    -- below creates an anonymous table with two properties (character, and id) and
    -- adds it to the end of table 'names'.
    table.insert(names, {character = cha, id = idx})
    -- or 
    -- names[count] = {character = cha, id = idx}
end
```

that logically groups the info the way you want it, and the data would look roughly like this in the table:

```
{ {character = 'H', id = 1}, {character = 'e', id = 2} ... }
```

and if you wanted the id from the first item in the table, you would reference it like what you did above:

```
local first_id = names[1].id -- access property id from table in first index in table names
```

Comment: WOW! that really cleared things up for me. Thanks for the detailed reply, I'm quite new to LUA. This is exactly what i'm trying to say and looking for. Question: To access this i need to use the "in pair" function in a for loop right? Thank you so much.

Comment: yeah, pairs() and ipairs() are the two most commonly used functions to enumerate tables... you can also use next(). feel free to mark my reply as the answer if it answered all of your concerns :)

Comment: Thanks again VBRonPaulFan for a detailed reply that a newbie like me could understand.

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues with your code:

1. You're indexing from 0 up. Lua starts indexes at 1. The for loop should start at 1.
2. You're assigning a string into the table, and then trying to assign to the id field of the string. Except strings don't have fields. This is what's actually throwing the error.

Comment: 1.So with that, can i start with 2 and not mind 1? can this also be a cause? 2.So, Something like this cannot be done once it is assigned with a String? am i correct?

Comment: @ronel: 1. `for count = 1, #str` is all you need to change there. `string.sub(str, 0, 0)` will always return `""`. `string.sub("foo", 1, 1)` will return the `"f"` you expect in that case. And the indexes into your `names` table will go from 1 to the length of `str`. As for 2., you probably want to do something like `names[count] = {}; names[count].string = string.sub(str, count, count); names[count].id = count`, which will store a table containing both the substring and the id.

Comment: thank for the reply. Yes, ok i now know how the for loop works. My main problem is the "names[count].id" i cant seem to do that. It keeps returning an error. My purpose is that i would like to have tagging along side the content of the array. Like names[count].alias or names[count].isActive something like that. Can I do that with this?